# Do I have to obtain a permit if an electrician does the work?

Tags: electrical, inspection

I'm looking at installing a new 220V outlet in my home garage.  My town requires a permit for any alteration to an electrical system. Typically, if a certified electrician installs this for me do I still need to obtain a permit and have an inspection done?

Comment: I would check with your local inspector. In my area, if you pull a permit as the owner, you are responsible to make sure your meet code, if your contractor pulls it, they are responsible. That is a way for a shady contractor to get out of fixing an issue.

Not saying all that use this method are bad.

Comment: I already upvoted Mike's comment but I can tell you that there are lots of complaints from people who get the permit for the contractor. If you don't want him waiting in line grab the form from City Hall and you do the leg work beyond filling the form out. I would strongly recommend that all contractors get the permit and the homeowner doesn't pay more than 75% until the City approves all work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the deal you make with the Electrician.  It's common for the Electrician to get the permit, though not unheard of for it to be the homeowners responsibility. The only way to know for sure is to ask the Electrician, or read through the contract/estimate.

It's also typical that if the Electrician pulls the permit, the cost will be passed along to you. You'll likely see it in the estimate/bill, as **Permit**. You may also notice that the price the Electrician charges, is a bit higher than what the permit office charges. This is because the Electrician will likely bill you for the time they spend dealing with permit issues (filing, waiting in line, etc).